# Can I define a Java subclass in ruby, then instantiate it in Java?

Tags: jruby

I'd like to define a superclass in Java, then define a subclass in Ruby, then make instances of that subclass in Java.  A little something like this:

```
// Java superclass
package myPkg;

public class Sup{
  public Sup(){}
  public abstract void foo(String a);
}
```

--

```
# Ruby code
include Java
require 'jruby/core_ext'

include_class 'myPkg.Sup'

class RubySub < Java::myPkg.Sup
  def foo( a )
    puts a;
  end
end

RubySub.become_java!
RubySub
```

--

```
// Back in Java land
Ruby runtime =  Ruby.newInstance();
IRubyObect ro = runtime.evalScriptlet(theRubyCodeAbove);
Class<Sup> clz = (Class<Sup>) JavaEmbedUtils.rubyToJava(runtime, ro, Class.class);
clz.newInstance().foo("Hey!");
```

I've tried the above code, but I get an InstantiationException from the `newInstance()` call.  I want to have the class declared in Ruby at runtime, so e.g. running jrubyc to compile the Ruby code to a Java class definition ahead of time is out.  What am I doing wrong here?

I've run through the bottom code segment in the debugger, and I'm definitely getting a RubyClass object returned from the `evalScriptlet()` call.  Maybe there's an extra step involved to turn a `RubyClass` into a `Class`?

---

UPDATE: I have [a lead](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6105) -- apparently `become_java!` doesn't work if the class is a subclass of a Java class.  Is there another way I can do this, or am I just boned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've come up with a workaround for now, but it's not pretty.

In brief: I can't return `RubySub.become_java!` (which is `nil`, because of [JRUBY-6105](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6105)) or try to return `RubySub` and convert from a `RubyClass` to a `Class`.

Instead, I return `RubySub.method(:new)`, which shows up as a `RubyMethod`. I can call this, and it creates an `IRubyObject` which is actually an instance of the subclass.  This can be cast to the Java superclass using `JavaEmbedUtils.rubyToJava()`.  Like I said, it's not pretty but it works.

Comment: Interesting... I was referred to your question from [my own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368726/adding-to-a-jruby-classs-getdeclaredmethods/18389490?noredirect=1#18389490)  

In my case, I tried your above solution with a class that inherits from VBox (javafx):  
    `class Controller < Java::javafx.scene.layout.VBox; end`  

With no luck:   
    `#<NameError: no method 'rubyToJava' for arguments (org.jruby.proxy.javafx.scene.layout.VBox$Proxy2) on Java::OrgJrubyJavasupport::JavaEmbedUtils>`

Comment: The `rubyToJava` call that I'm making takes 3 arguments -- the runtime (`Ruby`) instance, the object (`IRubyObject`), and the target (i.e. Java parent) class.  Yours would look like `JavaEmbedUtils.rubyToJava(myRubyInterp, theController, VBox.class)`.

I read your question, and it's a shame that framework code is outside your control.  Calling `getDelcaredMethods()` is a terrible, un-ruby-ish way to solve the problem, when they should have used `respond_to?`.

Comment: The third party in this case is java code (which I have no affiliation with, or command of), which is using reflection to see all functions defined in the (now) java-ized version of my class.  So in this case what I was hoping for was that ruby methods would automatically be seen in the java-ized version of the code and could be called from the java class.  This sounds like it might be a different than what you're trying to do above. Either way I was hoping become_java would do it, like you have it here, but it seems as though it does not.

Comment: A quick aside: I had also tried java_signature to do this, but that seems like it has no effect.  I'm not sure if it's related to the become_java issue or not... it looks as though there have been other java_signature issues, referenced [here](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6751?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:worklog-tabpanel).  I'm also probably outside of the scope of your post now as well - if so my apologies.